# How to create RxJS chained observable where the inner observable gets rebuilt

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've been bumping my head against an RxJS problem that I just cannot figure out.

#### Chained (completing) observable pattern

```
// pseudocode

http-request -> 
  do-another-http-request -> 
    returned combined result

// - chain is always triggered from the outer observable
// - chain completes after each cycle
```

#### Chained (non-completing) observable pattern:

The problem I want to solve is slightly different in that it doesn't complete but it has the same chained observable nature.

```
blog-post_with_category:
  -> on-category-id-change
    -> return observable of category from datastore

// As shown above, the blog post could either be switched
// to a new category (category_id:6 -> category_id:7)
//
// OR the category itself could change in the datastore i.e. a
// category with a particular id could have an updated 
// label (id:3, label:'Sailing' -> id:3, label:'Nautical')
```

#### When put into code, the pattern doesn't work:

```
export class BlogPostClass{

  postData: PostData
  category$: Observable<Category | undefined>
  private categoryId$: Subject<string>

  constructor(postData:PostData, categoriesQuery: CategoriesService){

    // Create an observable for the category ID
    this.categoryId$ = new Subject()

    // update the data & trigger ID to emit
    this.update(postData)
    

    // Chained observable  ------------------------
    this.category$ = this.categoryId$.pipe(
      mergeMap((newCategoryId:string) => 
        // observable of category from datastore
        this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(newCategoryId)
      )
    )
    //-----------------------------------------------
  }

  // ensure that new category ID is emitted on update
  update(postData:PostData):void{
    this.postData = postData
    this.categoryId$.next(postData.category_id)
  }
}
```

#### The outer observable triggers updates but the inner doesn't

Subscribing to the resultant chained observer shows that it updates when the outer observer updates but not when the inner one does:

```
post = new BlogPost(postData)
post.category$.subscribe((newCategory) =>
  console.log('label: ' + newCategory.label)
)

post.update( {category_id: newValue } )
=> label: new category label

post.category.update( {label: 'different label'} )
// nothing is printed into the console
```

What's missing?

```
this.category$ = this.categoryId$.pipe(
  mergeMap((newCategoryId:string) => 
    this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(newCategoryId)
  )
)
```

Comment: Why do you use `take(1)`? The `take(1)` causes the inner observable to emit once and complete so it will never emit again. But you want the inner observable to emit multiple times  (on every `post.category.update`) if I understand you correctly. I would remove the `take(1)` and use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`.

Comment: @fridoo yes I think you're right (edited and updated accordingly). However even with that in play it doesn't work. I'm beginning to wonder whether I've got the nesting the wrong way around - whether really what I'm trying to do is to write something more like: `this.category$ = this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(this.categoryId$)` - that wouldn't work as I couldn't pass an observable into the .selectEntity method but it's kind of what I want...

Comment: Are you sure `post.category.update( {label: 'different label'} )` causes `this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity` to emit? Could you post the code for `post.category.update` and `this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity`.

Comment: Good question and yes - I am sure as I'm also subscribing to them directly in addition to this. The `.selectEntity` functionality is from Akita [and is documented here](https://datorama.github.io/akita/docs/entities/query-entity#selectentity). the post.category.update is done by just injecting new data into the akita datastore which I know causes it to re-emit from `.selectEntity` because of the other bindings in the page

Comment: all that said - when I put a `tap` on the inner observable it does NOT emit when the associated data updates. Although when I create an equivalent observable elsewhere in the page and bind it to the view it does update. So needless to say I'm pretty confused!

Comment: As far as rxjs is concerned `this.category$` will emit whenever the inner observable `this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(newCategoryId)` emits. If `this.category$` doesn't emit when you think it should then `this.categoriesQuery.selectEntity(newCategoryId)` doesn't emit. You seem to map to an inner observable that doesn't get triggered when you call your update function. To get more help you should provide the code for your custom services and akita stores that are involved. Or better yet provide a stackblitz that's reproducing the problem.

Comment: Fridoo you’re absolutely right, the problem is elsewhere, not in the observable construct. I’ve been experimenting with interval observable to better understand how they work and everything you said is right. Something is wrong with the way I’m triggering and subscribing to updates. When I figure it out I’ll tell you what had caused it